# How does windows pass arguments to the executing file?

Tags: windows, antivirus

I have a pretty silly question.
Let's say I have an antivirus solution that allows me to block certain `.exe` files (in my case this is `wscript.exe`) and it also allows me to check arguments being passed.
For instance I run in cmd shell the following command:

```
>wscript.exe C:\virus.js
```

My settings in antivirus work well when I run the command as above.

When I just do double-click on `.js` file the antivirus doesn't work.
So my question is how does Windows act when I do double-click on `.js` file. Is it special system calls or just passing arguments with special flags?

Comment: there is no command line arguments?

Comment: Did you control that the default program associated with `.js` files in Config Panel / Default Programs is `wscript.exe` (or *Microsoft ® Windows Based Script Host*)?

Comment: Yes. This is wscript.exe

Comment: So far as I can see, Windows would just run `C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe "C:\virus.js"`

Comment: You can double-check this with Process Monitor, available from the MS web site.  But perhaps your anti-virus is just being confused by the full path, or perhaps by the quotes around the argument?

Comment: You are right. I forgot about quotes. Thx.